# Vuetify icons not centered inside button

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to use a Floating Action Button in Vuetify, but the icon doesn't line up with the button:

[image: android-screenshot]

Here's how I installed Vuetify:

```
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
import 'material-design-icons-iconfont/dist/material-design-icons.css'
import 'babel-polyfill'  // Required by Vuetify for IE11-era browsers

Vue.use(Vuetify)
```

Here's a CodePen showing what I'm doing: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vrXrYg?editors=1000

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar color="indigo" dark fixed app>
      <v-toolbar-title>My App</v-toolbar-title>
    </v-toolbar>
    <v-content>
      <v-container fluid fill-height>
          <div id="my-vue-component">
            <v-btn
                   fixed
                   fab
                   bottom
                   right
                   color="pink"
                   >
              <v-icon>
                microphone_off
              </v-icon>
            </v-btn>
          </div>  
        </v-container>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The icon you are looking for is simply called `mic` in the official material design icons doc. Changing from `microphone_off` to `mic` did the trick in your codepen.

see https://material.io/tools/icons/?icon=mic&style=baseline

Comment: Additionally, the vertical centering was broken by my webpack importing the material icons CSS after importing the Vuetify CSS. When I put Vuetify CSS last the icon was completely centered.

Answer (score 0):

I think the icon name is not suitable.You should get reference from https://material.io/tools/icons/
The icon name should be 'mic_off' instead 'microphone_off'
Also, Vuetify document says that Material Design Icons supported with mdi- prefix.